# Clearcase: prevent clearcase from removing CR while checking in

Tags: version-control, clearcase, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-automation

I have a text file, it uses CRLF as line terminator.
when I check in the file, clearcase removes CR and leave LF only.

How to prevent such a behavior ?

I'm using clearcase on windows

Answer (score 0):

On way ts to set a [text mode file](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/about_view_text_mode.htm).

The other is to modify the global setting:

- type `clearhomebase`
- onglet Options
- click on "User Preferences"
- onglet View
- Deselect the "Text Mode Option".

Comment: @becks then a default text mode (https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_ccrc_config_tmode.htm) must be active on your Vob.